# What are the orbits in the space of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I am self studying Linear Algebra and recently have learnt about orbit structures and group actions so I thought about combining those two ideas and giving myself some questions to test myself. I came up with this question:

> What are the $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$-orbits in the space of symmetric matrices under the action $S\rightarrow ASA^T$ where $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

but I am having trouble making sure about my answer and with the prove also.

My answer: I just got three orbit structures, the fixed point $\{0\}$, the positive definite matrices and the negative definite symmetric matrices. Now I know there are other orbits as well because the notes say there are 4 more that I can find easily. But honestly even finding the above ones took me some time after doing some research and I am not sure if they are correct even
.

P.S: The fact that I was able to find the positive and negative definite matrices is because of the action, it preserves the signature of the matrices.

Comment: The orbits for this group action are exactly described by the rank and the signature. So you forgot the orbits with rank $1$ (there are two orbits), and the orbit with rank $2$ and signature $(+1,-1)$.

Comment: @Jasmine See [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe How would i get orbits of rank 1 ? I tried finding them but failed. Could you kindly show me an element example?

Comment: Well, actually, every symmetric matrix *must* belong to an orbit. So for example, you should have one orbit containing the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
What I say is that the rank and the signature of a matrix entirely characterize its orbit, which means that two matrices with same rank and same signature belong to the same orbit.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I know that orbits form a partition of the space but didn't know a clear way of describing different orbits. Thank you for making it clear.  a sudden question thou, since i am studying about metric spaces and open sets, I wanted to know which of these orbits will be open sets? I don't want a proof, just an answer that i can compare my answers with later. Thankyou.

Comment: Well, that's an interesting question :) I think that you should be able to prove that the orbits containing non-invertible matrices (i.e. the null orbit and the two orbits containing rank $1$-matrices) are not open, and that the two other ones are open. Of course, when you see them as subsets of the space of symmetric matrices.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I was able to find orbits of rank 2 and orbit of positive signature and I was able to prove they belong to symmetric matrices ( by the definition of of the group action ) but I don't see the first one to be open set( I actually failed to prove that its open)? could I bother you to ask for an example of how could i show that?